# Django: update with conditions

Tags: python, django

I want to update an object through a form in Django but before doing `form.save()` in the view I want to do some conditions about the data.

For example:

```py
ire = get_object_or_404(Ire, id_IRE=pk)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = IreForm(request.POST or None, instance=ire)
    if form.is_valid():
        if ire.get_att1()==form.cleaned_data.get('att1') and ire.get_att2()==form.cleaned_data.get('att2'):
           form.save(update_fields=['type']) #just update the field type
        else:
           form.save() #create a new object
```

When I did this in my view just the first condition works but when I change the att1 or att2 in the form it does not do any changes.

Please help me how can I do conditions before saving!!!

Comment: Can you please paste your code properly. Just use three backticks before the code block, and three more after the code block?

Comment: why can you pass `update_fields` to your form's save method? Have you changed the form's `save()` method? And why do think `form.save()` creates a new object?

Comment: When you say that when you "change att1 or att2", what are you doing? ``form.cleaned_data['att1'] = foo``?

Comment: MonoHearted it is an update form so when i click the button update it triggers the form filled with values of the object that i want to update .i have three fields in the form att1 and att2 and type  i have two divise my code to two conditions the fi

Comment: MonoHearted it is an update form so when i click the button update it triggers the form filled with values of the object that i want to update .i have three fields in the form att1 and att2 and type so   i have two divise my code to two conditions if i change the type i have just update the type but if i change the att1 or attr2 i have to save the form so that it changes all the fields

Comment: because my model contains other attribute whose values are calculated based on these three attributes att1 att2 and type

Comment: so if i change the type i have just to update the type not all the other attribute which are not visible in the form ,because i do form.save ther are some attribut which may be incremented and i don't want that

Comment: the other condition which is modifying att1 or attr2 if do so i have to do form.save() to call the save method of the model so all the fields of the object will be modified based on the new values of attr1 and attr2

Comment: @dirkgroten if i do just save() other fattribut values  will be changed each time i do update that's why i want to divise my code to two conditions first if i modify just the type so in this case i have to update my object to just put the new value of type without modiying the others and the second condition is when i modify the values of attr1 and att2 in this case i have to do save

Comment: `form.save(update_fields=['type'])` would normally throw an exception because a normal `ModelForm`'s `save()` method doesn't have that parameter. You don't see an exception? If not, show us your form's `save()` method because it means you override it.

Comment: the problem i faced is that the value of attributes of the object which i want to update changes simultaneously with what i enter befor calling form.save i checked this by print method, so to solve this i store the values of the ire object befor calling the model form so keep the ancient values in variables, in doing so i manage doing my conditions : ire = get_object_or_404(Ire, id_IRE=pk)
    ire_att1=ire.get_att1()
    ire_att2=ire.get_att2()
    ire_type=ire.get_type()

Comment: if request.method == 'POST':
        form = IreForm(request.POST or None, instance=ire)
        if form.is_valid():
             if ire_x==form.cleaned_data.get('x') and ire_y==form.cleaned_data.get('y'):
                 Ire.objects.filter(id_IRE=pk).update(type=form.cleaned_data.get('type'))
             else:
                 form.save()

Answer (score 0):

thank you i found the solution which is storing the values of the object that i want to update befor doing the update operation :

```
ire = get_object_or_404(Ire, id_IRE=pk)
**ire_att1=ire.get_att1()**
**ire_att2=ire.get_att2()**
**ire_type=ire.get_type()**

if request.method == 'POST':
  form = IreForm(request.POST or None, instance=ire)
  if form.is_valid():
    if **ire_att1**==form.cleaned_data.get('att1') and **ire_att2**==form.cleaned_data.get('att2'):
          Ire.objects.filter(id_IRE=pk).update(type=form.cleaned_data.get('type'))
    else:
          form.save()
```

this is how i solve the probleme because i found that after calling the form model the values of the object change simultaneously with what i enter even before i call form.save